# How to get percentage of number with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was working on an app to learn (count down timer), I want the font color to be green from start and change to red whenever it is 15 percent of the time allotted. I have done most part of it but still, I can't get it right to make it turn red when it is 15% of the allotted time. Please help me out.

Here is how I declared the `If` statement:

```vb
percentage = ((15 / mm_Label.Text) * 100)

If hr_Label.Text Or mm_Label.Text Or ss_Label.Text = percentage Then
    hr_Label.ForeColor = Color.Red
    mm_Label.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ss_Label.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
    hr_Label.ForeColor = Color.Green
    mm_Label.ForeColor = Color.Green
    ss_Label.ForeColor = Color.Green
End If
```

Comment: How you calculate the percentage of time left depends on how you are storing the allotted time and how you are decrementing the remaining time during each tick. If you add your code from within the Timer_Tick() event, you will get a more useful and specific answer

Comment: Thank you very much @soohoonigan. I must confess that i don't understand what you mean by storing the allotted time(reason, i am new to visual basic), i am decrementing  the remaining time during each tick by -1 and also i added my code within the Timer_Tick()

Comment: Hi Steve , you're should be using an Integer conversion mechanism here such as CINT or Integer.Parse here.

Comment: Besides, are you a Nigerian?

Comment: @preciousbetine, thanks so much for your quick response. Please, can i get an example from you? Even if using the lines i attached.

Comment: @preciousbetine, i am a Nigerian sir.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant in my comment is that you need to know a few things to calculate a percentage of time left: when the timer started, when it ends, and how far along between there you are at each tick. I can't see the rest of your code so I can't say for sure why it isn't working, but I can demonstrate the concept with a simple example. Create a brand new WinForms project, paste this code directly into the new form, and run it:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Lbl As New Label With {.Width = 200}
    Dim started As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim timeOut As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
    'Dim timeOut As DateTime = Date.ParseExact("07/08/2019 18:01", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Controls.Add(Lbl)
        Dim tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000, .Enabled = True}
        AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf tmr_Tick
        tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim diff As TimeSpan = timeOut - DateTime.Now
        Dim totalSeconds As Integer = (timeOut - started).TotalSeconds
        Dim elapsedSeconds As Integer = diff.TotalSeconds
        Dim pctRemaining As Integer = CInt((elapsedSeconds / totalSeconds) * 100)

        Lbl.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} ({3}% Remaining)", diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds, pctRemaining)
        If pctRemaining < 15 Then Lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

End Class
```

This example just sets `timeOut` to one minute in the future, but you can set the value of it to anything by parsing a string into a datetime like in the commented-out line. I encourage you to read the code carefully, and step through it if necessary. Everything in the New() sub is just setting up the label and timer, what you really need to be concerned with is saving the DateTime that you started your countdown (`started`), the DateTime that the countdown will end (`timeOut`), and calculating the difference between them during each tick inside the `tmr_Tick` event. I think the code in there is pretty self explanatory, but in summary you're just seeing how much time is left until `timeOut` with the `diff` TimeSpan and displaying it as your countdown timer. For the percentage calculation, you're just looking at how many seconds out of the total have passed to get a percentage. You would then just need to check if that percentage is <15 and change the text color if so.

Comment: @soonhoonigan, thank you very much. I can't explain how happy i am right now, your points are well explained! Thank you.

Comment: I must really confess that you've helped me in a big way sir. I have done just what you said but i'm left with one issue. I used 3 NumericUpDown (Hour, Mins and sec) how do i initialize it here Dim timeOut As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)

Comment: Get the values from the 3 NumericUpDown and create timeOut like `Dim timeOut As DateTime = Date.ParseExact("07/08/2019 [hours]:[min]:[sec]", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)` replacing the brackets in the string with the values. If the timer is never more than a day, then you can replace the date in that string as well with a simple DateTime.Now.Year/Month/Day